# Not able to run 'npm install' on vagrant homestead

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp, laravel-elixir

I'm trying to install Gulp & Elixir on my Laravel project but I keep getting errors when I run 'npm install'. I've also tried 'sudo npm install' but no luck there.

My Node version is: 1.4.14

It switches between these two:

[image]

For this error there was a solution posted here: https://harvsworld.com/2015/how-to-fix-npm-install-errors-on-vagrant-on-windows-because-the-paths-are-too-long/

But this has not solved the issue seeing it still happens after following the steps.

I also sometimes get these errors (the list goes on...):
[image]

Anyone know a solution? I haven't found anything yet after a couple hours of searching..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search I eventually found the solution.
Seeing I'm using Homestead / Vagrant, I was using PuTTY. This was my first mistake. 
Just simply use Git Bash, just make sure you run it as an administrator &
change the directory to your Laravel project.

The second thing you need to do is make sure you don't have a 'node_modules' file in your project. Just remove the files by doing:

```
rm -rf node_modules/
```

Followed by:

```
npm install
```

Everything should work now. It's a dumb mistake but hopefully through this post, people will not make the same one as I did and waste alot of time doing it..

Cheers!

Comment: I have this issue also, but im purposely trying to run it via putty, since i want to leverage the speed of the vm over ming64/cygwin, etc.. i have tried them all, this is way faster.  i need to be able to run this via putty, is this even possible for putty ssh to write to homestead shared repo like this?  its working until i get symlink and perm issues, even using --no-bin-links.  I especially want to run the `npm run watch` this way.

Answer (score 0):

You should first [install node](https://nodejs.org/download/) in your local machine.

Then, navigate to your project folder and run (again on your local machine!):

```
npm install gulp --save-dev
```